# R stan 8schools example faile

Tags: r, stan

I am trying to run classical r-stan example from this official [tutorial](https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/wiki/RStan-Getting-Started#how-to-use-rstan). But I can't because I get the following error message:

[image]

The code I use is as follows:

```
schools_dat <- list(J = 8, 
                    y = c(28,  8, -3,  7, -1,  1, 18, 12),
                    sigma = c(15, 10, 16, 11,  9, 11, 10, 18))
fit <- stan(file = '8schools.stan', data = schools_dat, 
            iter = 1000, chains = 4)
```

Where 8schools.stan is file I have additionally created and nested with the following code:

```
data {
  int<lower=0> J; // number of schools 
  real y[J]; // estimated treatment effects
  real<lower=0> sigma[J]; // s.e. of effect estimates 
}
parameters {
  real mu; 
  real<lower=0> tau;
  real eta[J];
}
transformed parameters {
  real theta[J];
  for (j in 1:J)
    theta[j] = mu + tau * eta[j];
}
model {
  target += normal_lpdf(eta | 0, 1);
  target += normal_lpdf(y | theta, sigma);
}
```

***I want to figure out the reasons of this error and how to avoid it***.

Additionally I want mention that:

1. The following code works propertly and returns 10:

   fx <- inline::cxxfunction( signature(x = "integer", y = "numeric" ) , '
       return ScalarReal( INTEGER(x)[0] * REAL(y)[0] ) ;
   ' )
   fx( 2L, 5 )
2. I have installed latest frozen version of Rtools.
3. Also, Rtools, R and Rstudio are located in folders without spaces.
4. I work on Windows (not laptop)
5. I have been strictly following all the steps from [installiation guide](https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/wiki/Installing-RStan-on-Windows).

Will be very greatfull for help!

**Update**

I also have set Sys.setenv(USE_CXX14=1) as Ben Goodrich has suggested but now I get the following error message

[image]

Comment: The error or warning rather that I see is the `StanHeaders version is ahead of the rstan version`. Upgrade or first install? I see that the the install test works, but these bread crumbs suggest removing everything, including any prior installs, and including any prior objects created by rstan (assuming a prior install), and reinstalling to get the versions right. HTH, Chris

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply! I have installed rstan for the first time.I also tried to remove and reinstall StanHeaders package but the error remains.

Answer (score 2):

This is a temporary issue due to the fact that (this week) the StanHeaders R package (which requires C++14) has been accepted on CRAN but not yet the rstan R package (which uses C++14 to compile the models). So, for the time being, you first need to call

`Sys.setenv(USE_CXX14=1)`

But anyone reading this post much in the future is unlikely to need to do that explicitly (the rstan R package will do it internally).

On Windows you need to put

`CXX14=g++ -std=c++1y
CXX14FLAGS=-O3`

into the ~/.R/Makevars file but on a Mac, those lines should already be there.

Comment: And all is right with the world. Does @Bogdan need to check his build tools environment for availability of CXX14, or rather how might he, and me?

Comment: @Betn Goodrich thank you for reply, but now I get a new error that I have mentioned in the post above (see update section)

Comment: I updated my answer. Stan now requires `g++-4.9` (as is used by RTools on Windows) or `clang++-4.0` (which on a Mac is what comes with the compiler [installer](https://github.com/coatless/r-macos-rtools#how-do-i-use-the-installer). The corresponding (or later) versions of `g++` or `clang++` should be fine on any Linux. Solaris is a known unknown.

Comment: @Bogdan Try again after adding those two lines your ~/.R/Makevars file from the updated answer.

Comment: Then is says that "clang++: not found"

Comment: What does your ~/.R/Makevars file have in it currently? Basically, you need to make the `CXX14` line look exactly like the `CXX` line and make the `CXX14FLAGS` line look exactly like the `CXXFLAGS` line.

Comment: Is it the way it should look like (each in different row)?
CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS=-O3
CXX14=g++
CXX14FLAGS=-O3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181562/discussion-between-ben-goodrich-and-bogdan).